# How to create a custom buttons grid in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I have a React component that I want to place at bottom of the screen. It should stay there regardless what's on top of it. If there is almost no content on top of it, it should still stay there.

I solved it by adding `style={{position: 'fixed', bottom: 0}}` to the main `div`

Now, I want to have a grid that looks kind of like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uqKe.jpg). Whatever I do, they end up on each other making [no sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ8tr.jpg) at all.

What I tried: bootstrap, putting them grouped in `divs`, flex directions etc.

**Here's the code:**

```
render() {
        return(
            <div style={{position: 'fixed', bottom: 0}}>
                {/*Fix elements as footer*/}

                <div style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20, minHeight: 200}}> A </Button>
                </div>
                <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A </Button>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A </Button>
                </div>
                <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A </Button>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A </Button>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A</Button>
                </div>
                <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A </Button>
                    <Button variant="raised" color="default" style={{fontSize:20}}> A </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I don't know, but I always struggled with css no matter how much I read about styling. If anyone has some tips to create custom layouts please educate me.
Bootstrap is easy for creating a simple layout, but I can't wrap my mind around css and it always steals most of my time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Bootstrap classes if you actually intend to use Bootstrap.

Here's one way to achieve the desired grid layout for those buttons:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid fixed-bottom">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-100 btn-outline-primary">A</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-50 btn-outline-secondary">B</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-50 mt-0 btn-outline-success">C</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-danger">D</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block mt-0 btn-outline-warning">E</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block mt-0 btn-outline-info">F</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-dark">G</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-100 mt-0 btn-outline-primary">H</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `btn-lg` or `btn-sm` classes can be used to make the buttons large or small. The `btn-block` makes it full-width of the column. The `no-gutters` on the row removes the column paddings/gutters and `h-100` or `h-50` means "height:100%" and "height:50%" respectively.

And here is how the entire row can be nested inside another Bootstrap column:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            col-sm-3 content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100vh">
            col-sm-9 content
            <div class="row no-gutters mt-auto">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-100 btn-outline-primary">A</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-50 btn-outline-secondary">B</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-50 mt-0 btn-outline-success">C</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-danger">D</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block mt-0 btn-outline-warning">E</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block mt-0 btn-outline-info">F</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-dark">G</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block h-100 mt-0 btn-outline-primary">H</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes `d-flex flex-column` on the column turn it into a flex column and the `mt-auto` class (margin-top:auto) on the row pushes that row to the bottom of that column. And `style="min-height: 100vh"` makes sure that the column height is at least the same as the viewport height (so that the buttons stay at the bottom even if there's hardly any content in the parent column).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense, I didn't even know I could use something like `h-100`. This component is rendered in `App.js` and is placed in a `"col-sm-9"`. The above code goes over this border. Here's a [visual](https://imgur.com/a/u4tbM) - Any way to make it render only in the right column?

Comment: You need to nest it in that `col-sm-9` column. So, put the entire row from my snippet (without the container) inside that column.

Comment: Mhh, does something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/c22Kv) not suffice?

Comment: As I said, in my snippet, the row sits inside a Bootstrap container. If you want to nest the row inside a Bootstrap column, use just the row for nesting but not the container.

Comment: The container in my snippet has the class `fixed-bottom` which naturally does what it's supposed to do. Anyway, even without that class, containers shouldn't be nested. Only a Bootstrap row can/should be nested inside a Bootstrap column.

Comment: Sorry I misread that. Somehow it get's [squished](https://imgur.com/a/x1TFz) a lot, nevertheless I'll try fixing it. Thanks a bunch. Why shouldn't containers be nested?

Comment: Almost fixed it with `width: '100%'` in the [row](https://imgur.com/a/KUm6z) class.

Comment: I added a second snippet for the nesting case.

Comment: Added the classes `d-flex flex-column` to the column and `mt-auto` (margin-top:auto) to the row in the second snippet to make sure that row always sticks to the bottom of that column. And `style="min-height: 100vh"` makes sure that the column height is at least the same as the viewport height.

Comment: [It](https://imgur.com/a/dkK89) just won't go over the whole screen. I'm most definitely messing up somewhere else. If I use a fixed width it works. Thanks for the explanation to the classes and for your time.

Comment: Remove your custom css. I'm not using any custom css.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand how the CSS works, here is a code without Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container row">
   <div class="column flex-1">
     <button class="flex-1"> A </button>
   </div>
   <div class="column flex-1">
      <button class="flex-1"> B </button>
      <button class="flex-1"> B </button>
   </div>
   <div class="column flex-2">
      <button class="flex-1"> C </button>
      <button class="flex-1"> C </button>
      <button class="flex-1"> C </button>
   </div>
   <div class="column flex-2">
      <button class="flex-1"> D </button>
      <button class="flex-2"> D </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 2;
}
```

And the fiddle to illustrate :
https://jsfiddle.net/dnotkL5w/16/

`flex: 1` means: "Take all the available space, in the direction specified by the container". So, if the container is in row, it will take all available space in width.

`flex: 2` means "Take all the available space, in the direction specified by the container. If there is a `flex: 1` item in the container, be twice its size".

That's a barycenter : the number given to the `flex` property will indicate the component size ratio compared to its siblings.

Comment: Thanks, never really understood flex in its entirety.